# AWS ec2 instance IAM user but root user not seeing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have a client and he has given me IAM access to my email to his AWS account.

and I have logged in successfully and then lunch an EC2 instance to his account as IAM user.

But the client not seeing the instance to his side as a root user.

What is the possible issue?

Like my clint aws account email `client@example.com`

and my email `jhondoe@gamil.com`

Client given me IAM access to his aws account with my mail `jhondoe@gamil.com` and lucnh EC2 instance there in my side.

But client not seeing the istance i lunched to his account, client logged in as a root user, coz, he is owner of the account with lie this `client@example.com`

I am new to AWS, can anyone help me in this case?

Comment: Probably regions like MLu says. You should tell the account owner to stop using the root account, create himself an IAM account with the permissions he needs and lock away the root account password for in case it's really needed. All accounts should have MFA enabled as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you’re in a **different region**.

In the top-right hand corner there’s a drop-down menu with regions - make sure that both you and your client are in the same one, e.g. Oregon or wherever you have created the EC2 instance.

Hope that helps :)